# MySQL Join Tables with Multiple Duplicate Values in Join Columns

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, rdbms

**Constraints**

- Tables are de-normalized
- Cannot use sub-query

**Tables**

Name: Locations

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       | auto_increment |
| zip_code  | varchar(12) | NO   |     |         |                |
| city      | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| county    | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| state     | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| info      | varchar(99) | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Name: Addresses

```
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+-----------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default   | Extra |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0         |       |
| address_one      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |           |       |
| address_two      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |           |       |
| city             | varchar(30)   | NO   | MUL |           |       |
| state            | varchar(25)   | NO   | MUL |           |       |
| zip_code         | varchar(7)    | NO   | MUL | NULL      |       |
| country_code     | char(2)       | YES  |     |           |       |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
```

**The Problem**

- Tables *Locations* and *Addresses* will have `state` duplicated across many rows.
- *Locations* table has around 100k rows and the *Addresses* table has about 1M rows.

**The Question**

I need to get a unique list of `states` with their `info` from the *Locations* table where there is at least one address in the *Addresses* table for any the respective `state`.

Any join I have, without using sub-queries, ends up taking forever.

What query will satisfy the **Constraints**?

Comment: And why do you have such constraints?  If this is a homework problem, it is polite to describe it as such *explicitly*.

Comment: Not a homework problem. Was trying to be forced into believing that ANY use of a sub-query including in this case was a performance issue. I think sub-query is the right way to go.

Comment: This smells like a query posted (and addressed) on another forum.  If so, cross link.

Answer (score 1):

It is a myth that subqueries are a performance problem. Sometimes they are; sometimes they are not.  There is no such simple rule.

In your case, I might suggest:

```
select l.*
from (select distinct state, info
      from locations l
     ) l
where exists (select 1
              from addresses a
              where a.state = l.state
             );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `locations(state, info)` and `addresses(state)`.

There are two subqueries, but with appropriate indexes, this may just be the fastest way to express this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT state, info FROM locations LEFT JOIN addresses USING (state) WHERE address_one IS NOT NULL GROUP BY state;
```

That query does not use a subquery.

Comment: If there are many rows with the same state in both tables, which there are, this query matches ALL of them and is extremely slow.

Comment: @webish, oops that's correct.  I've added a GROUP BY at the end to make it only distinct states.